# QML faster button clicking

Tags: qt, button, qml

Is is it possible to speed up the "clicking" of the button in QML? At the moment, I can click the mouse as fast as I want but the button sends a "clicked" signal maximum 3 times per second :/

```
Button {
    text: "Click me"
    onClicked: console.log("clicked")
}
```

Comment: Will MouseArea allow any faster click? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html and that BTW also depends on the OS and the hardware setting.

Comment: with some simple logic using Date.now() I have tested how many times I can click and see no limit to click speed. I have been able to click up to 12 times per second with no discernible misses. It sounds like you have OS problems or some other performance issue.

Comment: @AlexanderV Thanks, with MouseArea there is no such a problem, but it stylistically stands out from the rest :/

Comment: @fallerd I'm working on fresh HP Omen laptop with fresh Win10. Could you check the button also with "Universal" GUI styling?

Comment: @dany I set universal style in my test app by using QQuickStyle::setStyle("Universal"); It did change the style of the button, but did not change the rate of clicks I can achieve.

Comment: what happens if you click more the 3 times? The button doesn't respond?

Comment: Button still works, but slow (cannot get faster "clicked" signals from the user)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The button doesn't emit the clicked signal on each mouse release cause there's a delay to allow emitting the doubleClicked signal without the clicked signal.

If you want a signal on each mouse release, use the `released` signal.

```
Button {
    text: "Click me"
    onReleased: console.log("clicked")
}
```